# Establish SSH connection on an ActiveDirectory Windows machine

Tags: git, ssh, permissions, active-directory

I am currently working on a machine inside of an active directory. Thus my home directory is located on a network drive (in this case drive-letter *h*). I now wanted to pull a git repository via ssh from a Gitlab-instance inside the same network. Unfortunately, the ssh connection cannot be established with the error message:

*Load key "/h/.ssh/id_rsa": Permission denied*

So I compared the permissions of my other (working) local machine with the ones on my network-home-directory and they match up exactly. Three entries (SYSTEM, actual user & the admin-group) with full access as can be seen in the following [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEkBn.png).

The complete ssh-output from ssh -vvv git@server:

```
$ ssh -vvv git@server
OpenSSH_8.4p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1h  22 Sep 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /h//.ssh/config
debug3: kex names ok: [diffie-hellman-group1-sha1]
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/h/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/h/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug2: resolving "server" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to server [xx.xxx.xx.xx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /h/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /h/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /h/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /h/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /h/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /h/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /h/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /h/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /h/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /h/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /h/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /h/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /h/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /h/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u8
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u8 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to server:22 as 'git'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/h/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
The authenticity of host 'server (xx.xxx.xx.xx)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/h/.ssh/known_hosts).
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /h/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:XXXXXXXXXX/XXXX/XXXXX+XXXXXXXXX/XX/XXXXXXXX
debug1: Will attempt key: /h/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /h/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /h/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /h/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: /h/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /h/.ssh/id_xmss
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /h/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:XXXXXXXXXX/XXXX/XXXXX+XXXXXXXXX/XX/XXXXXXXX
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: /h/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:XXXXXXXXXX/XXXX/XXXXX+XXXXXXXXX/XX/XXXXXXXX
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:XXXXXXXXXX/XXXX/XXXXX+XXXXXXXXX/XX/XXXXXXXX
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using ssh-rsa SHA256:XXXXXXXXXX/XXXX/XXXXX+XXXXXXXXX/XX/XXXXXXXX
Load key "/h/.ssh/id_rsa": Permission denied

debug1: Trying private key: /h/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /h/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /h/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /h/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /h/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug3: no such identity: /h/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /h/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /h/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /h/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug3: no such identity: /h/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /h/.ssh/id_xmss
debug3: no such identity: /h/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
git@server's password:
```

I managed to pull repositories on active directories on other machines in the past, so clearly I am missing something.

Has anyone else faced similar issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check first with which account your GitLab instance is running.

If it is not yours, it might not have permission to access your own HOME on the network drive H:\

The [OP Sebastian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1379475/sebastian) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65087842/establish-ssh-connection-on-an-activedirectory-windows-machine/65104166#comment115261471_65104166):

> As if this isn't strange enough, it suddenly just worked normally since yesterday. And that without any further changes since a week ago.
>
> Maybe it was a fixed issue with Windows OpenSSH or something.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution! The GitLab Server is running inside my LAN, not on my machine. Private keys shouldn't be available to other services outside of the machine it is stored on. So as far as I understand it, the ssh script (or the git script) cannot access my private key for the verification process.

Or do you mean the script-executing user? If so, then yes, it is my own domainuser with the HOME directory set to H:\.

Comment: @Sebastian Yes, but with *which* account is it running? If it is not your own account, it won't have access to your network drive.

Comment: Ah ok. It is my own domainuser with the HOME directory set to H:\. I can even cat the content of the key within the same terminal session.

Comment: @Sebastian Right, but is the GitLab process launched with your account? Or as a service, with the Windows System account?

Comment: The Gitlab instance is running on a debian machine with the default gitlab useraccount.

Comment: @Sebastian OK. Does that account has the right to access your network drive?

Comment: I start to doubt my understanding of private/public key authorization^^. No it does not have the right to access my drive. And it should never have this right. In this case the debian system does not even have mounted this drive. This permission error must be raised locally. The only thing that has changed in this setup, is my new laptop I use to establish the connection.

Comment: @Sebastian "private/public key authorization": simple: the process trying to ssh will need to access %HOME%\.ssh. If HOME is set to H:\, it will try to access H:\. If it does not have the right to access it... ssh won't work.

Comment: Yeah thats right. But it is the local ssh-script trying to establish a connection to gitlab, not gitlab trying to ssh to my machine. And it does _see_ the file, but cannot _read_ it apparently. But as I stated, i can cat the contents of the file regardless.

Comment: @Sebastian Which account is used by the ssh-script when it is running? Is it running as a Windows service?

Comment: I am running the ssh command on my windows machine via powershell without administration rights. _whoami_ returns my local user registered in AD. $HOME returns my network homedrive H:\.

Comment: @Sebastian Can you double-check / reapply ownership, as in https://superuser.com/a/1311633/141?

Comment: Yes I have, now the SYSTEM user, and Administrators group have been removed. But unfortunately, this didn't has an effect.

Comment: @Sebastian Can you do the same for the .ssh folder itself, not just id_rsa?

Comment: Done. Unfortunately also no luck.

Comment: @Sebastian Can you add to your script a simple `type H:\.ssh\id_rsa`, to see if that script can indeed access the file (independently of SSH)? Check also the output of "set": is there any environment variable related to ssh?

Comment: I tried that, and had no issues to print the content of the file. I found that very strange and dug a little bit deeper. Apparently, the issues lays in the git command. As I always successfully accessed the files directly from the powershell, in the now tried git-bash on the other hand, I cannot cat the content. There I get *cat: id_rsa: Permission denied*.

Comment: @Sebastian That is why I was asking about any environment variable which includes SSH in it. Check also the output of `git config -l` (for anything related to "ssh")

Comment: `git config -l` has nothing regardless of running it under cmd or gitbash.
`set`returns nothing under cmd and `PLINK_PROTOCOL=ssh` under gitbash

Comment: @Sebastian I would make sure that variable environment is not defined, as well as your %PATH% does not include anything related to putty, in order to not interfere with the regular openSSH which comes with recent Windows 10.

Comment: I checked that and tried many other things but nothing worked for me. As if this isn't strange enough, it suddenly just worked normally since yesterday. And that without any further changes since a week ago. Maybe it was a fixed issue with Windows OpenSSH or something. I will mark this answer as correct and will report if I manage to get more information about why it is suddenly working.

Comment: @Sebastian Strange indeed. Did you made a Windows update?

Comment: At least not on purpose. But who knows what windows does in the background..
Many thanks for your efforts @VonC.